# Is this the correct $PATH on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions

I have this as variable PATH on my PC

```
~$ echo $PATH
/home/username/.local/share/umake/bin:/home/username/bin:/home/username/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Is that ok? How is that my local user folders have priority over the other folders? Isn't possible that someone can create a file called for example ls make it executable, put it on .local/share/umake/bin and I will execute whatever is on that file when trying to use the ls command?

Comment: That's the point - if you wanted to override system `ls` with a newer version you compiled and install, then `~/bin` is a good place to put it. Do others have permissions to write in your home folder? If so, they could do all sort of stuff, and `PATH` wouldn't be all that high on my list of concerns.

Comment: If it helps my path is: /home/user/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: Thanks. Yes other have permissions to write in my home folder but I'm the administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find it unusual. `~/.local/share/umake/bin` is, of course, where `umake` installs stuff, and `~/.local/bin` is where `pip install --user` commands end up, and probably other things. `~/bin` is added to the `PATH` if you create that directory. If a user installs commands to these directories, they would reasonably expect those commands to take precedence over the system utilities.

> Isn't possible that someone can create a file called for example ls make it executable, put it on .local/share/umake/bin and I will execute whatever is on that file when trying to use the ls command?

Why go to that much trouble, instead of, say, editing your `~/.bashrc` to replace `ls` with a function?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I didn't think of that but that's true. It just appeared to me that it wasn't the best to let anyone without root administrative privilegies to easily override basic system binaries on a default terminal but now I understand the logic in that.